# Protected access to class-constructor

Tags: java

I have
 `class User`
that contains protected constructor and

```
class Account
```

that has access to this constructor, but Account doesn't extends User.

How can it be??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think, that User and Account are in the same package. Protected access is alsoo Package access

Answer (score 1):

If your classes are in the same package, this is expected behavior:

> The protected modifier specifies that the member can only be accessed
>   within its own package (as with package-private) and, in addition, by
>   a subclass of its class in another package.

- [Controlling Access to Members of a Class<sup>Oracle</sup>](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

Answer (score 0):

`protected` access is looser than package-access. Basically, any class in the same package can use `protected` scoped constructs.

Specifically, see [JLS 6.6.2.2 Qualified Access to a protected Constructor](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/names.html#6.6.2.2)

> ... A protected constructor can be accessed by a class instance creation expression (that does not declare an anonymous class) only from within the package in which it is defined.